# How to create multiple conditioner login in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model

my model is here.....but i need to select status of admin ....... but
 i m new in codeigniter....and don't no how to select... my need is...
 select admin whole detail  from table on condition admin status =
 active and id=1...

my model is :

> public function login($value) {
>
> ```
>     $query = $this->db->get_where('tbl_admin', $value, 1, 'active');
>
>
>     if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
>
>         $row = $query->row_array();
>
>         $sess_arr = array(
>             'admin_user' => $row['fld_admin_username'],
>             'adm_key' => $row['fld_admin_key'],
>             'admin_type' => $row['fld_admin_type'],
>             'admin_id' => $row['fld_admin_id'],
>             'admin_logged_in' => TRUE
>         );
>
>          $this->session->set_userdata($sess_arr);
>          //echo "<pre>";print_r($this->session->all_userdata());exit;
>     }
>     else{
>
>         $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Invalid username/password');
>  redirect('adminzone');   
>
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for the first line would be:

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('tbl_admin', array('id' => 1, 'status' => 'active'));
```

I.e. The second parameter to get_where is an associative array of fields and their values..

Edit: Or perhaps it should be

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('tbl_admin', array('id' => $value, 'status' => 'active'));
```

(I am not sure what the $value variable is for here).